# how to solve orientation issue?

Tags: android, orientation

I want to make 480x800, 600x800, 600x1024 and 800x1280 resolution layouts.

i have to show both orientation(portrait and landscape) with resolution 600x800, 600x1024 and 800x1280 and resolution 480x800 show only landscape mode.

Right now it is showing both orientation mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nga.swp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="false"
        android:smallScreens="false" android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PhraseListActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

my issue is how i am able to show landscape mode only with resolution 480x800. 
what changes i have to do in my menifest file.

Comment: If I rephrase your question: you want to limit landscape mode for 480x800 devices only?

Comment: i have to show both orientation for screen resolution(600x800, 600x1024 and 800x1280) and only landscape mode for screen resolution 480x800. Right now it is showing both mode for all resolution and work nicely except 480x800 screen resolution. becoz i need only landscape mode for it.

Comment: @Laurent how can i limit landscape mode for 480x800 devices only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to have conditional layouts is by using qualified directory names inside the /res directory.

But in your case, you would need to change the android:screenOrientation of your activity. Alas, it is in the manifest and it does not seem to be setable in your activity layout.

So, I guess you have to use code in your activity onCreate.

First get the screen dimension using:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then conditionally adapt screen orientation using :

```
if((width != 480) && (height !=800))
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

See [`ActivityInfo.screenOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation) for further orientation modes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make

```
layout-land

layout
```

put your xml in that.

480x800, 600x800, 600x1024 and 800x1280 resolution layouts for that..

you should make `drawable-ldip, drawable-mdip, drawable-hdip` folder and put your images in that.

Android direct take & differentiated resolution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your device resolution by using:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
```

Then get the device's height & width using `display.getHeight()` and `display.getWidth()`.

It is much easier to do the next operations.

You can use `OrientationListener` in order to check the orientation.